# Difference in 2 dates to be fetched in days format

Tags: angular8

this.diffDays[0] = Math.round(Math.abs((this.creationDate - this.todayDate)));
this is the condition I provided..If my creationDate is 15/10/2019 and todaydate is 16/10/2019, I should get the answer as 1..Instead of that i am getting 0..

Answer (score 0):

Use (yyyy-MM-dd) date format.

for Example,this.diffDays[0] = Math.round(Math.abs((2019-10-15) - (2019-10-16))));